# Flash replacement plugin for Firefox?

Tags: firefox, flash

Is there something I can install instead of Flash, that will substitute for a Flash plugin - on Firefox/Windows ?

and that uses significantly less CPU resources?

Comment: Flash is a proprietary format there are no replacements to Flash that support Flash at this time.

Comment: Nowadays there are alternatives, in fact alternatives are the only working solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nothing written in Flash can be displayed using *less* resources than modern FlashPlayer versions, to the best of my knowledge (though the modern versions are much more efficient than the older ones). There are, however, multiple attempts to create an open-source clone of FlashPlayer that can be used as an alternative. Most of them primarily target Android or desktop Linux, which - unlike Windows - do not get official builds of new Flash version anymore. However, most of these Flash alternatives can also be used on Windows.

The ones that are likely most interesting to you:

- [Mozilla Shumway](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shumway_(software)). An extension to Firefox that translates Flash applets into JavaScript and HTML5 content, which the browser then executes directly. Available here: https://mozilla.github.io/shumway/
- [Lightspark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lightspark) is a replacement plugin for Flash. It may also depend on [Gnash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gnash), an older Flash-replacement plugin. Both primarily target Linux-based systems but can be built for Windows. Download Lightspark [here](http://lightspark.github.io/), and Gnash (if needed) [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/gnash/).

Comment: I have _enable hardware acceleration_ checked (when you right click the video playing) but it sure doesn't feel like it.

Comment: Do you have proper graphics drivers installed? All non-antique (last ~7 years) GPUs, even integrated ones, support video decoding in hardware. It does require that the driver know how to tell the chip to do it, though. Reallllly old GPUs (especially integrated ones) may lack the feature, though.

Comment: yeah but it's really confusing.. it's an NVIDEA mobile GPU that keeps switching back and forth between the integrated (core i5) one. So I'm really not sure if I have everything properly configured..